# downvotes not subtracting reputation

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

I downvoted twice on English SE, and each time my reputation stayed the same. Is this a bug, or are there some conditions under which no reputation is subtracted from downvoting?

Comment: did you downvoted questions or answers ?

Comment: both were questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Downvotes are free on:

1. questions, and
2. community wiki answers.

Comment: Even Upvotes are free on Community Wiki Answers.

Comment: @Lucifer Hm? Upvotes are free in general ("free" in the sense that they don't cost the voter any reputation).

Comment: yeah, i know that part, my top answer on SO was CW.